# Apache Hive: Parse Exception

Tags: hive, hiveql

this is my query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_DB.TEST_V
AS
   SELECT RECEIVING_INVENTORY_ORG_ID AS RECEIVING_INVENTORY_ORG_ID,
          BL_LINE_KEY                AS BL_LINE_KEY
     FROM (SELECT TEST_T.RECEIVING_INVENTORY_ORG_ID,
                  TEST_T.BL_LINE_KEY
             FROM TEST_DB.TEST_T) TEST_DB.TEST_V;
```

i am seeing below error while executing

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 7:64 missing EOF at '.' near 'TEST_DB'
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Subquery alias should be without database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_DB.TEST_V
AS
SELECT RECEIVING_INVENTORY_ORG_ID AS RECEIVING_INVENTORY_ORG_ID,
       BL_LINE_KEY                AS BL_LINE_KEY
     FROM (SELECT TEST_T.RECEIVING_INVENTORY_ORG_ID,
                  TEST_T.BL_LINE_KEY
             FROM TEST_DB.TEST_T
          )s; -- this alias is wrong in your query
```

And you do not need a subquery at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
    FROM (SELECT TEST_T.RECEIVING_INVENTORY_ORG_ID,
              TEST_T.BL_LINE_KEY
         FROM TEST_DB.TEST_T) TEST_DB.TEST_V;
```

The subquery is aliased as TEST_DB.TEST_V. 
Hive is complaining about a '.' in the subquery name. 
Try a subquery name without a '.', say TEST_V.

Comment: Please improve your explanation